# No input file specified when typing homestead.app as the url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

So I have installed laravel through composer, the virtual box machine and homestead. Everything is fine but now when I try to access the url homestead.app as shown in the instructions, I get the No input file specified. Below is the content of my homestead.yaml... for the folders, I pointed it to my local area where I have the laravel source called installed under XAMPP/htdocs... What am I doing wrong ?

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/xampp/htdocs/learning-laravel-5/public
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is a bit off I believe.

First you map your project's public directory to you virtual box's Code directory. Then you map your site  to the Laravel/public directory inside the directory you just mapped. So in fact you are trying to access `C:/xampp/htdocs/learning-laravel-5/public/Laravel/public` from you web server, which probabaly doesn't exist.

Personally I would map my VM's Code directory to my htdocs folder. This way you will have access to all files in there from inside your VM. Your site should be mapped slightly diffrent as well then. I believe it would look similar to this:

```
...    
folders:
    - map: C:/xampp/htdocs
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/learning-laravel-5/public
...
```

Also, don't forget to set up a host to have homestead.app point to the correct IP (192.168.10.10)

Comment: I am still getting the no input file specified .. what's wrong with that ?